How to define an array of dynamic types using OpenAPI?
I want to define a schema for a data structure that contains an array with values ​​of different types:
{
  "some_array": [
    "string_value0",
    "string_value1",
    "string_value2",
    {
      "some_nested_array": [
        {
          "some_value0": "value0",
          "some_value1": "value1",
          "some_value2": "value2"
        }
      ],
      "some_value": "value"
    }
  ]
}

I tried to do it this way, but all the generators I use don't assume that some_array can have values ​​of different types:
components:
  schemas:
    SomeArraySchema:
          type: object
          properties:
            some_array:
              type: array
              items:
                oneOf:
                  - $ref: '#/components/schemas/PlainTextElement'
                  - $ref: '#/components/schemas/ComplextElement'

    PlainTextElement:
      type: string

    ComplextElement:
      type: object
      properties:
        some_nested_array:
          type: array
          items:
            type: object
            properties:
              some_value0:
                type: string
              some_value1:
                type: string
              some_value2:
                type: string
        some_value:
          type: string

For example, here is the error produced by code generated by OpenAPITools openapi-generator:
Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at path $.some_array[0]

How to define some_array properly to handle different types of its values?

Your OpenAPI definition is correct. The issue seems to be with the code (Java? Kotlin?) generated by the openapi-generator. Search their issue tracker to see if it's a known issue, or open a new issue https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues
